# Number Partitions With Unique Difference but Symmetrical

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For an even integer $n$, line up the integers from $1$ to $n$ so that:
the differences are all different in one half but symmetrically the same in the other
example for $14$:

$$7 \ \ 1 \ \ 10 \ \ 2 \ \ 3 \ \ 6 \ \ 4 \ \ 11 \ \ 9 \ \ 12 \ \ 13 \ \ 5 \ \ 14 \ \ 8$$

Clearly the additional symmetry around the centre is $n+1$
e.g. $15=11+4=9+6=12+3+\cdots$

Can you always do this?
if so, in how many ways for given $n$?

Can it be made into a cycle so that the 'centres' also have the same difference?
(e.g. above $8 \ \ 7$ is diff $1$ but $4 \ \ 11$ is diff $7$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make the pairs $(k, n+1-k)$  for $k$ from $1$ to $\frac n2$.  The first $\frac n2$ numbers must be one of each pair, but otherwise there is no restriction, and the last $\frac n2$ numbers are fixed.  That gives $\left(\frac n2\right)!\cdot2^{n/2}$ possibilities.  I am not sure there are no more.

As each pair has a unique difference of $n+1-2k$ this approach cannot close the cycle.